# Call AfxBeginThread with class member function?

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, boost-bind, member-functions

How can I call AfxBeginThread with an arbitrary non-static class method? Maybe there is something I can do with [boost bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/bind)? Below is the expected usage from Microsoft (and is an example of calling a non-static method but it is hard-coded which method):

```
UINT MyThreadProc( LPVOID pParam )
{
    CMyObject* pObject = (CMyObject*)pParam;

    if (pObject == NULL ||
        !pObject->IsKindOf(RUNTIME_CLASS(CMyObject)))
    return 1;   // if pObject is not valid

    // do something with 'pObject'

    return 0;   // thread completed successfully
}

// inside a different function in the program
...
pNewObject = new CMyObject;
AfxBeginThread(MyThreadProc, pNewObject);
```

Comment: You already have the solution. You posted it in the question. In what way is it not sufficient for you?

Comment: What I'd like to be able to do is execute an arbitrary class member function in a thread like you can do with boost thread.  My posted example works but it's hard coded to a particular class.  I would like to use boost thread but it seems there are some issues when using it in an MFC context.

Comment: You have to call your member function where there is the placeholder comment "do something with 'pObject'". Sorry, but that's just the way it is.

Answer (score 5):

You will need a static function to pass to AfxBeginThread, but it can be a very simple function that calls into the object. Here's an untested template function that might work.

```
template<class T>
UINT __cdecl StartThread(LPVOID pParam)
{
    return ((T*)pParam)->MyThreadProc();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code sample is fine. You will need a thread function for each different non-static class method you want to call in separate threads.

boost:bind will not help you whatsoever... AfxBeginThread would have to be a C++ template function, otherwise it cant be compatible with boost::bind or C++11 lambdas with captures.

One Alternative is to create a struct, with an enum for each class/method combination you will have, but this still requires you to manually add code to both the enum and the callback function for each class/method combination. However its not that much less code than creating a separate thread function for each class/method combination.

```
struct ThreadData
{
  LPVOID object;
  enum ObjectCallType {
    Foo_Foo,
    Foo_Bar
  } objectCallType;
  LPVOID* param;
  ThreadData( LPVOID pobject, ObjectCallType poct, LPVOID* pparam=0 )
  :object(pobject), objectCallType(poct), param(pparam) {}
};

UINT MyThreadProc( LPVOID pParam )
{
    TheadData* thData = (ThreadData*)pParam;
    try 
    {
        switch( thData->objectCallType )
        {
            case ThreadData::Foo_Foo:
                Foo* foo = (Foo*)thData->object;
                foo->foo();
                break;
            case ThreadData::Foo_Bar:
                Foo* foo = (Foo*)thData->object;
                foo->bar( thData->param );
                break;
            default:
                throw std::exception("unhandled method call type");
        }
    }
    catch( std::exception& e )
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        delete thData;
        return 1;
    }
    delete thData;
    return 0;
}



//usage:
AfxBeginThread(MyThreadProc, new ThreadData(myFooObject,ThreadData::Foo_Bar,myFooCallParam));
```

Boost example (untested):

```
boost::thread myFooFooThread( boost::bind( &Foo::Foo, myFooObject ) );
```

Comment: I don't have experience with boost bind.  Could you pass a boost bind object as the parameter to `MyThreadProc` and then have MyThreadProc simply call the boost bind function?

Comment: @User: no you cant, because you would have to cast the boost::bind object from LPVOID to the actual object, and thats not trivial, because pretty much every boost::bind object has a different (complicated) type. You can however use boost::bind objects with boost::thread.

Comment: given that I wonder if you could use boost::bind with a templated StartThread function as in Mark Ransom's answer.

Comment: @User: yes you can, but you will still have to specify the type of the bind expression as template parameter, and this is very troublesome, unless you can use the C++11 features `auto` and `decltype` or `std::function`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is pretty old -- but it's close to my current situation.  I am working on an application written in Visual Studio 2008 project, and would like to avoid all the start functions.

What I found is there are two different invocations of AfxBeginThread: One requires the start function (for launching working threads); the other takes, as its first parameter a class derived from CWinClass and is used for creating User Interface connected objects AND worker threads.

I am choosing the second option.  Would this not also work in the above question?